# Why Try Catch dont working on VideoPlayer Prepare() method?

Tags: unity-game-engine, try-catch

I want to catch an exception when the url for VideoPlayer is broken, but try{}catch{} didn't catch this exeption.

```
VideoPlayer cannot play url : http://migration.com:8080/video/test.mp4

Cannot read file.
```

My method

```
public async void Initialize(string url){
    errorText.text = string.Empty;
                              
    _videoPlayer.url = "http://migration.com:8080/video/test.mp4";
    _videoPlayer.audioOutputMode = VideoAudioOutputMode.AudioSource;
    _videoPlayer.targetTexture = rendererTexture;
             
    _videoPlayer.errorReceived += OnPlayerErrorReceived;
        
    try{
        _videoPlayer.Prepare();
        while (!_videoPlayer.isPrepared)
            await UniTask.Yield();
     }
      catch{}
    }
```

Has anyone solved this problem

Comment: Ever since Unity 2017 you could use .NET Framework 4.x and the corresponding `async/await` keywords.  Why use a 3rd party _UniTask_ library (that upon random inspection is multiplexing "tasks" on the UI thread much like ugly coroutines)?

Comment: ...also "yield"ing a logical _task_ makes no sense.  A _task_ is a _high-level concept_ and does not necessarily represent a thread. Yield is typically concerned with lower-level aspects such as _threads and processes._  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.yield?view=net-6.0

Comment: I read that UniTask is faster and more optimized than Task. This is not true?

Comment: _” I read that UniTask is faster and more optimized than Task. This is not true?”_ - what’s more likely? An unknown library makes extraordinary claims or the handful of developers of an unknown library are more skilled than the entire .NET Task Parallel Library team at Microsoft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see in the console is not the result of an actual `Exception` that is thrown and could be handled by the `try - catch`.

Unity rather already internally handled this and only prints a `Debug.LogError` / `Debug.LogException` for this

=> There is nothing actually thrown you can `catch` here.